# Android Debug INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

Tags: android

We are confrunting with an **INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT** , logcat error : *LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=2080*.
We found this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22586

and we are wondering how the they compiled the dalvik to optain so much debug information.

Example:

```
D/dalvikvm( 7815): --- LinearAlloc(interfaces, 0x0, 20)
I/dalvikvm( 7815): --- old=3330796 size=20 new=3330820 now at=3326720
D/dalvikvm( 7815): CLASS: linking 'LTest$H4;'...
D/dalvikvm( 7815): --- LinearAlloc(iftable, 0x0, 781240)
I/dalvikvm( 7815): --- old=3330820 size=781240 new=4112068 now at=4107968
D/dalvikvm( 7815): --- LinearAlloc(interfaces, 0x0, 20)
I/dalvikvm( 7815): --- old=4112068 size=20 new=4112092 now at=4107992
D/dalvikvm( 7815): CLASS: linking 'LTest$H5;'...
D/dalvikvm( 7815): --- LinearAlloc(iftable, 0x0, 781240)
I/dalvikvm( 7815): --- old=4112092 size=781240 new=4893340 now at=4889240
D/dalvikvm( 7815): --- LinearAlloc(interfaces, 0x0, 20)
I/dalvikvm( 7815): --- old=4893340 size=20 new=4893364 now at=4889264
D/dalvikvm( 7815): CLASS: linking 'LTest$Z;'...
D/dalvikvm( 7815): --- LinearAlloc(iftable, 0x0, 3906240)
I/dalvikvm( 7815): --- old=4893364 size=3906240 new=8799612 now at=8795512
E/dalvikvm( 7815): LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=3906240
```

Thank you.

Comment: I am using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

According to the issue you linked its a problem resulting from long chains of interfaces. It was fixed in 2012 (https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/30900/), so it shouldn't be an issue in newer versions of Android.

Are you using Scala? More debugging will not help you then, as you cannot shorten the inheritance chain easily. A newer version of Scala might help.

Comment: I am not using scala, and the problem appears only on Gingerbread, so the fix update does not help. My only concern is how to optain the debug information.

Comment: Ok @elvisrusu, I'm afraid I can't help you with that.